# Python: Get contents of pointer to pointer to structure coming from C dll to Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I have a structure in C and loading data into it.

```
struct service { char a[150]; char b[150]; };


void Food1(struct service ***p, int* pSize) {
    int i;
    *pSize = 2;
    struct service **pReturn = (struct service **)malloc(2 *sizeof(struct service *));

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pReturn[i] = (struct service *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct service));
        if (i == 0) {
            strcpy(pReturn[i]->cTitle, "6757");
            strcpy(pReturn[i]->cValue, "1234");
        }
        else {
            strcpy(pReturn[i]->cTitle, "FRIEND");
            strcpy(pReturn[i]->cValue, "9786");
        }
    }
    *p = pReturn;
}
```

Now, i am trying to get pReturn values from Python. When I run my python code I am getting the size (2nd parameter). but, not the data (pReturn values). Here is my Python code.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

class SERVICE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cTitle", c_char_p),
        ("cValue", c_char_p)]

Foo = ctypes.CDLL(r"c:\users\fred\desktop\GetFileAttributes.dll")
Foo.Food1.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(POINTER(SERVICE))),POINTER(c_int)]
mem = POINTER(POINTER(SERVICE))()
size = c_int(0)
Foo.Food1(byref(mem), byref(size))
print ("Size: {}".format(size.value))
print (mem)
```

How do I display the content (In my case, 1st argument (mem)) from C DLL (pointer to pointer to a structure) to python using ctypes?

When I try to run this code in Python 3.4 on Windows, the output was

```
Size: 2
<__main__.LP_LP_SERVICE object at 0x0000000001F62F48>
```

Comment: You should probably define argtypes for `Foo.Food1`, and not for the DLL.

Comment: I have updated in the script. But, that didn't work. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

the types in the SERVICE fields are incorrect.  `c_char_p` is equivalent to `char*` in C.  Instead you want `c_char * 150` which is equivalent to `char[150]`.  Then, since a pointer to an array of pointers is returned, dereference the array and get the pointer contents:

```
from ctypes import *

class SERVICE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cTitle", c_char * 150),
                ("cValue", c_char * 150)]

Foo = CDLL('test')
Foo.Food1.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(POINTER(SERVICE))),POINTER(c_int)]
mem = POINTER(POINTER(SERVICE))()
size = c_int(0)
Foo.Food1(byref(mem), byref(size))
print("Size: {}".format(size.value))
print(mem[0].contents.cTitle)
print(mem[0].contents.cValue)
print(mem[1].contents.cTitle)
print(mem[1].contents.cValue)
```

Output:

```
Size: 2
b'6757'
b'1234'
b'FRIEND'
b'9786'
```

Comment: Thanks mark. That worked. I need to free allocated memory. Probably, I will write a function in C side and will call that function from Python.